# Setup Chrome to use mailto: links under LXDE

Tags: google-chrome, thunderbird, lxde

I have Ubuntu 14.04 set up with a choice to sign into either Unity or LXDE as the desktop environment.

When I sign into Unity, mailto: links in both Chrome and Firefox work as I would like, opening a draft email using Thunderbird.

When I sign into LXDE, only Firefox works as I would like. When I click on a mailto: link in Chrome, it does nothing.

Thunderbird is my default email client in both desktops.

On another plain-vanilla Lubuntu setup in our house, Chrome works properly.

How can I get Chrome to act on mailto: links in the LXDE-over-Ubuntu setup?

Note: google search results often recommend setting this using chrome://settings/handlers.  But that does not have any options related to email. I suspect the functionality has changed since those answers were written.  It looks like this:

[image]